# PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS how to stop a call from being place? android

Tags: android

what can be done to stop outgoing calls from an android device for certain number at certain time. i am using the following permission: android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS

but the receiver is not able to stop the call

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />

     <receiver android:name=".receiver.NewOutgoingCallReceiver" android:exported="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" /> 
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

and here is the receiver code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
    Log.d("NewOutgoingCallReceiver",
            ">>>>>> Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER: "
                    + incomingNumber);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Call - " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    abortBroadcast();
}
```

The android system still places a call. In this demo I just want to system to stop placing all calls.

Comment: setResultData(null); does the trick ... stops the call from happening

Comment: now the problem is that when i want the Intent.ACTION_CALL to take care of calling ... it again hits my broadcast receiver and brings back the dialog ... is the only way to tell the broadcast receiver to ignore the next android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL?

Comment: is `android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` really needed?

Answer (score 10):

Use this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
 if (intent.getAction().equals(OUTGOING_CALL_ACTION)) {

          // get phone number from bundle
            String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(INTENT_PHONE_NUMBER);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Call:  "+phoneNumber+" - ABORTING CALL.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            setResultData(null);
      }
    }
```

Comment: abortBroadcast() is not needed, and not recommended ... just needed the setResultData(null) ... thx!!

Comment: is ``android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` really needed?

Comment: you made my day with setResultData(null)