# Can't prevent outgoing calls in Android using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm trying to build an application that kills outgoing call depending on the number called.
I have that code that works for incoming calls, but not for outgoing:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt < Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.P)
        {
            TelephonyManager mng = (TelephonyManager)(context.GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService));
            IntPtr iTelephonyPtr = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(mng.Class.Handle, "getITelephony", "()Lcom/android/internal/telephony/ITelephony;");

            IntPtr telephony = JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod(mng.Handle, iTelephonyPtr);
            IntPtr iTelephonyClass = JNIEnv.GetObjectClass(telephony);
            IntPtr iTelephonyEndCall = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(iTelephonyClass, "endCall", "()Z");
            JNIEnv.CallBooleanMethod(telephony, iTelephonyEndCall);
            JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(telephony);
            JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(iTelephonyClass);
        }
        else
        {
            TelecomManager telecomManager = (TelecomManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.TelecomService); 
            telecomManager.EndCall();
        }
```

I found nothing on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your Activity for the `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent in the app's manifest, and then handle that intent when an outgoing call is made.

I don't know if you can do this all from within c#. If you can receive intents, you should be able to get the one for making the phone call, and then determine how to stop the ongoing call.

There is a java only question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364112/process-outgoing-calls-how-to-stop-a-call-from-being-place-android/7364224), but it's quite old, and I don't know if it still works on modern android versions. (P and up)

The answer there suggested calling `setResultData(null);` in the handler which replaces the number with null, thereby cancelling the call. I don't know if that's possible from inside of xamarin.

Comment: FYI: For API level 29+ device, you need to use `CallRedirectionService` instead of the `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` intent

Comment: @SushiHangover is that an option or is it mandatory? Because this feature doesn't exist in API level <29. (every version of android that's been released as of writing) I though there's usually a deprecation period for android APIs.

Comment: Yes and no... Any *new* application that is uploaded that deals w/ `NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` / `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` will cause a Play Store review flag and you will be sent the policy notice about it (as not many app's are trying to replaced the system dialer or a voice assistant) and you would have to try to file for an exception (details are included in the policy notice they send you). Developers have been abusing those permissions for years and any app new or updated to support API 29+ has to change (and yes, lots of devs are mad, but, security should be 1st priority)...

Comment: FYI: The permissions side of the changes for those are already in place, that happened in P/28 : https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/

Comment: I expected it was some sort of security issue, if there was little to no advance warning. Do you know when they started flagging new uploads, and is there an androidx backport of the new functionality? Write your own answer, or edit mine if you want.

Comment: This was intro'd back during P/28 beta, so everyone should have known it was coming ‍♀️... So you can use those perms but : "It must be actively registered as the default Phone or Assistant handler on the device." and "...evaluated against any potential privacy or security impact on users. These exceptions are rare and will not be extended to all developers...." : https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/ And no, I have not heard of any back-porting of the new `CallRedirectionService` feature.

Comment: I know of devs that got exceptions granted, BUT, they have had apps in the Store for YEARS and because they were in good standings w/ security researchers, no user complaints, etc... but after API-29 drops, they will have to be using CallRedirectionService, if they wish to ever update their app again.

Comment: Thank you... but I don't find a `setResultData` in Xamarin nor the `CallRedirectionService` class :-(

Comment: Both of those things are java/Kotlin based. (and CallRedirectionService is new for the next version of android) You'll either have to use whatever java interoperability xamarin gives you to do this part, find a library someone else made, or wait for something like this functionality to be put into xamarin.